# GPU Intel&AMD in device manager but only Intel in dxdiag

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, gpu, amd-graphics-card

I use:

- HP Pavilion dm4-3001tx Entertaiment Notebook PC
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit

In [device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivPDH.png) it has two graphic cards.

[image: device manager]

But in [dxdiag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdWMB.png) it only has 1 graphic card.

[image: dxdiag]

And in several programs, it tells me that I need to configure my graphic card for better performance. Let's take `nox` for instance [image: http:// i.stack.imgur.com/SuHuN.png]

So, I'm guessing my AMD drivers is not installed properly.

I did reinstall my OS but I'm using the same windows as before (which is windows 7 64bit) and a driver from HP official site. I've also installed `HP Support Assistant` to check my drivers but everything is seems to be updated (according to HP Software).

Any solution to show my AMD graphic into dxdiag, or remove `nox` graphic suggestion (as it means no problem with my graphic cards anymore)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the AMD Catalyst settings tool, go to the [switchable Graphic Application settings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oB2oDO-IFk), click on "`Add application`" and select the exe of the game and set it to `high performance`.

[image]

This configures the driver to use your AMD card instead of the Intel HD.

Now download the tool call [OpenHardwareMonitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) and add the AMD Radeon HD7470M settings to the Gadget. if the GPU is not used you see this:

[image]

<sup>(look at the `-` at GPU Clock, Speed)</sup>

If the GPU is used you see this:

[image]

<sup>(here you see the speeds, the `V` disaply and the temperature and this means the AMD GPU is now used)</sup>

You should also install the latest [driver from Intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=HD%20Graphics%203000) and the latest [driver from AMD](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy3&os=Windows%207%20-%2064) and not use the older drivers from HP website.

Comment: When I configure the `AMD Catalyst` to high and run the game, I can see my AMD on `Hardware Monitor`, but it showing `-` on it. What should I do? note that I use driver from hp site, and check my driver with hp software but doesn't seem to have any problem

Comment: remove the Intel HD and AMD driver with DDU (http://www.wagnardmobile.com/?q=display-driver-uninstaller-ddu-), install the latest Intel HD driver (https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=HD+Graphics+3000) and the latest AMD driver ( http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy3&os=Windows+7+-+64 )

Comment: thanks installing directly from AMD website do the job, put your comment in the answer, So I can accept your answer

Comment: ok, I've added it to the answer