# Which GPU is being used by Windows?

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon, intel-graphics

I have two GPUs: Intel HD 5500 and AMD Radeon R5 M330.

I want to know which video card is being used when I'm watching videos on YouTube or just simply navigating through websites on Chrome.

When does Windows switch between them and how can I find out? I'm not playing games.

Comment: in [my answer I posted a way to see which GPU is used](https://superuser.com/a/1115632/174557). Configure in the AMD/driver dialog which GPU is used for a specific exe.